# Join fields row for first two columns equals

Tags: awk, csv

Im trying to obtain from this file:

```
A4690021|product.actor|Laurel Cronin
A4690021|product.actor|Bob Hoskins
A4690021|product.actor|Caroline Goodall
A4690021|product.actor|Julia Roberts
A4690021|product.actor|Maggie Smith
A4690021|product.actor|Amber Scott
A4690021|product.actor|Charlie Korsmo
A4690021|product.actor|Robin Williams
A4690021|product.actor|Dustin Hoffman
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Offline Best Seller
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Online Best Seller
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
```

This result:

```
A4690021|product.actor|Laurel Cronin,Bob Hoskins,Caroline Goodall,Julia Roberts,Maggie Smith,Amber Scott,Charlie Korsmo,Robin Williams,Dustin Hoffman
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Offline Best Seller,
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
```

Trying to use this awk script:

```
awk -F'|' '{a[$1"|"$2]=a[$1"|"$2]","$3}END{for(x in a)print x""a[x]}' SEARCH_ECISTORE_PRD_MULTI_ES_s.csv
```

But i don't know why i'm obtaining this:

```
A4690021|product.storeName,Cine
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id,999.54215013.999.54216013
A19129625|product.author,. VV.AA.
A4690021|product.director,Steven Spielberg
,Dustin Hoffmanllactor,Laurel Cronin
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName,Infantil
,Online Best SellerstSellers,Offline Best Seller
```

I'm having an issue when reading actors, it seems $3 contains the proper value but when aggregating them they kind of merge in strange ways..

Comment: I suspect stray characters in your source file.  Was it prepared on Windows?  If not, can you run `od -c SEARCH_ECISTORE_PRD_MULTI_ES_s.csv` and report the results.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the field dividers for the last field:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{a[$1"|"$2]=a[$1"|"$2]","$3} END{for(x in a)print x"|"substr(a[x],2)}' file.csv
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
A4690021|product.actor|Laurel Cronin,Bob Hoskins,Caroline Goodall,Julia Roberts,Maggie Smith,Amber Scott,Charlie Korsmo,Robin Williams,Dustin Hoffman
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Offline Best Seller,Online Best Seller
```

#### Line-wrapping issue

Let's convert the source file to DOS/Windows format:

```
$ unix2dos <file.csv >file.dos
$ awk -F'|' '{a[$1"|"$2]=a[$1"|"$2]","$3} END{for(x in a)print x"|"substr(a[x],2)}' file.dos
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
,Dustin Hoffmanllactor|Laurel Cronin
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
,Online Best SellerstSellers|Offline Best Seller
```

This looks like your problematic output.

The solution is to run `dos2unix` or other utility on it to remove the DOS/Windows line-endings.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate (because I do some time the same)

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\(\(.*|\)[^|]\+\)\n\2/\1, /;ta;P;D' SEARCH_ECISTORE_PRD_MULTI_ES_s.csv
```

will produce

```
A4690021|product.actor|Laurel Cronin, Bob Hoskins, Caroline Goodall, Julia Roberts, Maggie Smith, Amber Scott, Charlie Korsmo, Robin Williams, Dustin Hoffman
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Offline Best Seller, Online Best Seller
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
datamash -t\| -g 1,2 collapse 3 <SEARCH_ECISTORE_PRD_MULTI_ES_s.csv
```

Result:

```
A4690021|product.actor|Laurel Cronin,Bob Hoskins,Caroline Goodall,Julia Roberts,Maggie Smith,Amber Scott,Charlie Korsmo,Robin Williams,Dustin Hoffman
A4690021|product.director|Steven Spielberg
A4690021|product.bestSellers|Offline Best Seller,Online Best Seller
A4690021|product.parentCategory.id|999.54215013.999.54216013
A4690021|product.storeName|Cine
A4690021|product.parentCat.displayName|Infantil
A19129625|product.author|. VV.AA.
```